# vlc and cmd window appear when running tkinter app

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a tkinter app in python in which I use two modules: os and vlc. The problem is the following:

When I'm running the tkinter app and using that part of the application which needs os and vlc, the windows cmd and the vlc window pop up for a few seconds and then both of them disappear.

How could I eliminate the appearing of these two windows?

*EDIT*:

```
import vlc
import os

class PageOne(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        self.image_label = Label(self, text='your stream pics', font=controller.title_font)
        self.image_label.grid(row=0)
        print(self.framer)

    def framer(self, stream_url):
        full_path = self.create_folder() 

        req_value = self.create_vlc_command(full_path + '\\', stream_url)
        print(req_value)
        os.system(req_value)
```

function inside PageOne class that uses vlc module:

```
def create_vlc_command(self, full_path, stream_url):
    pre_sc_path = '--scene-path='
    file_name = pre_fn + self.get_date_time()
    vid_settings = ("--rate=1 --video-filter=scene "
                   "--vout=dummy --run-time=3 "
                   "--scene-format=png --scene-ratio=24 "
                   "--scene-prefix=") + file_name
    scene_path = pre_sc_path + full_path
    req_value = ("vlc {arg_name} {vid_settings} {scene_path} "
                 "{quit}").format(arg_name=stream_url,
                vid_settings=vid_settings, scene_path=scene_path,
                quit='vlc://quit')
    print('req_value: ', req_value)
    print('scene_path', scene_path)
    return req_value
```

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: how do you run code which shows window ?  Better show code.

Comment: What are you using VLC for?

Comment: if you use `os.system()` then it use `cmd` to run it. Better use module `subprocess`

Comment: @Novel I'm using vlc for getting screenshots of a stream.

Comment: what stream ? There is pythom module [MoviePy](https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy) to works with video.

Comment: BTW: I think there should be module to work directly with `VLC` without `os.system` or `subprocess`. If I run `pip search vlc` then it shows some modules with word `vlc`.

Comment: @furas I want to get pictures when pressing a button as fast as possible from (for example this stream) http://stream.e-cityguide.eu:1935/live/komarom.stream/playlist.m3u8 This is what I use vlc for. import vlc is in the beginning of my script! Do you know a better/faster solution? Thanks!

Comment: you import `vlc` but I don't use it in code - with module `vlc` you should have commands like `inst = vlc.Instance()`, `player = inst.media_player_new()`, `player.set_media()`, etc. like in example [tkvlc](https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/blob/master/examples/tkvlc.py). With `os.system()` or `subprocess` you run external `vlc` and you don't use module `vlc`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Which module would make faster the process I mentioned above?

Comment: with `subprocess` you can use current `req_value` because it runs external program similar to `os.system` - so it can take less time to do it - but it can display `vlc` window. With `vlc` you have direct access to library used by `vlc` and probably it doesn't display window - but it will need more works to learn new module.